# @FindBy with Arquillian Graphene using className

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, jboss-arquillian, graphene2

```
@FindBy(className = "shellTileBase")
  private WebElement tile;

@FindBy(className = "FilterDefault FilterIcon UiIcon IconMirrorInRTL")
  private WebElement form;
```

I am working with selenium and testng but am trying to add arquilliian to my testing. can arquillian handle

```
@FindBy(className ="")
```

With multiple class names as per my above example. When I run this I am getting  a:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Compound class names (class names with a spaces) cannot be used as selector in search by `className`. You can solve it using `XPath` as below:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='FilterDefault FilterIcon UiIcon IconMirrorInRTL']")
```

or `CSS`:

```
@FindBy(css=".FilterDefault.FilterIcon.UiIcon.IconMirrorInRTL")
```